# Google Docs Reference Sheet through Column Values

Tags: google-sheets

my A column have names of the sheet I would like to reference, but it's not letting me, here's my functions in for column B

`='A1'!E6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INDIRECT function should work for you.  Try:

`=INDIRECT(A1&"!E6")`

Comment: for some reason, i got to the forth row, it's giving me this error: Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is '4!E6'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.

Comment: seems like I have to have those tabs/sheets prior running this INDIRECT command, otherwise I have to redo the INDIRECT for it to load... it does not load on the fly as I create the sheets...